# iOS13 - problem with navigationBar title color

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios13, xcode11

I have a storyboard-app with several viewControllers and a tabBarController. Up to now the color of the title of the navigationBar was white. Now I'm testing with Xcode 11 beta 6 an iOS 13 beta 8 and the title are black. On devices with iOS 12 the title are still white.
I tried to set title color in the navigation bar of the navigation controller in the storyboard. But this makes no difference.
I also tried to change the title color in every view, but sometimes it doesn't work.
At the beginning of testing with iOS 13 I had to change my code for changing the backgroundcolor of the statusbar. The code is this:

```
self.tabBarController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"AppTitle",nil);

NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:COLOR_HEADER_LIGHT];

if (@available(iOS 13, *))
{
    UINavigationBarAppearance *navBar = [[UINavigationBarAppearance alloc] init];
    navBar.backgroundColor = COLOR_HEADER_LIGHT;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBar;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBar;
}
else
{
    UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];
    if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = COLOR_HEADER_LIGHT;
    }
}

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                 shadow, NSShadowAttributeName, FONT_MEDIUM_SIZE_18, NSFontAttributeName,
                                                                 COLOR_TEXT_WHITE, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:COLOR_TEXT_WHITE];
```

I hope anyone has an idea how to change the title color back to white. Best case without adjust every controller.

Comment: How is COLOR_TEXT_WHITE defined?

Comment: #define COLOR_TEXT_WHITE        [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS13 you need to set the title color on the UINavigationBarAppearance object - try adding this line to your code:

```
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: myAppLabelColor]
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: myAppLabelColor]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
func manageNavigationBar(){
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *){

            let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.6157, green: 0.3412, blue: 0.8588, alpha: 1.0)
            navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationController.self]).standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationController.self]).scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        }
    }
```

//call this function in your AppDelegate also in a class where you want navigation to work like this

Comment: Best answer for this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 13, I change the title color like this

```
UINavigationBarAppearance *appearance = [self.navigationController.navigationBar standardAppearance];
appearance.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
self.navigationController.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13 uses dynamic color for light and dark themes you can set the title color by creating a color asset for light and dark appearance.